# Ease time between firing specific number of timeouts in a specific period of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, settimeout, easing

It's kind of math problem. I want to fire specific number of `setTimeout` (the number is based on an *array* length) in a specific period of time (say, 5 seconds).

The first `setTimeout` should start at `0 sec.` and the last at `5 sec.`. All timeouts between should start with an *`ease-in`* effect, so that each timeout starts faster.

There's an example which ilustrates what I want to achieve exactly.
I'm struggling around this line:

```
next += timePeriod/3.52/(i+1);
```

which works almost perfect in demo example (for any `timePeriod`), but obviously it doesn't work for a different `letters.length` as I have used static number `3.52`.

How do I calculate **`next`**?

```js
var letters = [ 
  'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T'
];

var div        = $('#container');
var timePeriod = 5000; // 5 seconds;
var perLetter  = timePeriod/(letters.length-1); // it gives equal time between letters
var next       = 0;

for(var i=0; i<letters.length; i++){
  setTimeout(function(letter){
    //div.append('<span class="letter">' + letter + '</span>');
    // Used "|" instead of letter, For better redability:
    div.append('<span class="letter">|</span>');
  }, next, letters[i]);
  
  // Can't find the logic here:
   next += timePeriod/3.52/(i+1);
  
};


///////////////// FOR DEMO: ///////////////

var sec = timePeriod/1000;
var secondsInterval = setInterval(seconds, 1000);

var demoInterval = setInterval(function(){
  sec >= 0 || clearInterval(demoInterval);
  div.append('\'');
}, 30);

function seconds(){
  sec || clearInterval(secondsInterval);
  $('#sec').text(sec-- || 'DONE');
}
seconds();
```

```css
.letter{
  color : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id=container></span>
<span id=sec class=letter></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var steps = letters.length;
var target = timePeriod;

function easeOutQuad(t, b, c, d) {
  t /= d;
  return -c * t*(t-2) + b;
};

var arrayOfTimeouts = new Array(steps);
var n;
var prev = 0;
for(var i = 1; i <= steps; i++){
  n = easeOutQuad(i, 0.0, target, steps);
  arrayOfTimeouts[i-1] = n-prev;   
  prev = n;
}
```

This one should work with any input value.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spinvectorspinvector/y7xmfunk/1/)

Note that the graph appears to be slightly too fast but I believe that discrepancy to be a product of timing imperfections, as the sum of my array equals the timePeriod exactly.

[more on easing equations](http://gizma.com/easing/)

Comment: Thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution based on a geometric series.  It's a bit goofy but it works.  It generates an array with your timeout values.

Steps = size of your array.

Target = the total time.

```
var steps = 50;
var target = 5000;

var fraction = 1.5 + steps / 7;
var ratio = (fraction-1) / fraction;
var n = target / fraction;
var sum = 0;
var arrayOfTimeouts = new Array(steps);
for(var i = 0; i < steps; i++){
    sum += n;
    arrayOfTimeouts[i] = n;
    n *= ratio;               
}

console.log(arrayOfTimeouts, sum);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't seem to work: https://jsfiddle.net/m509um6m/

Comment: yep it breaks when you've only got 4 steps.  but hey it works when you've got like 10-100! ^_^

Comment: I'll give you a vote up for the `10-100` :) But still, it's not the answer I'm looking for.